# Needed C++ HTML parser + regular expression support

Tags: c++, html, android, regex, html-parsing

I'm working on a C++ project and I need to find an external library which
provides HTML parser and regular expression support.

The project is under 2 OS - iOS & Android.

I was thinking using libxml2 which has a HTML parser module and xml regular expression.

Can I use the xml regular expression module on HTML page?

In addition, I need some basic html function support in C++.
Like those 2 PHP functions: rawurlencode & urlencode.

I'm open to different libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used libxml2 to parse html, but I remember that it was easy to use for xml parsing, so probably it's worth a try.

For the regular expressions, instead, I would suggest you to use [Boost Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).